# improve temporary data store

Tags: c#, .net

I need your idead to improve our implementation.

we have about `10MB` data need to be processed in our application for `each analysis`. that data is transferred from another application packet by packet. there are about `24000 pakcets` for `each analysis` because the data is created packet by packet in that application and then sent to us immediately.

our current implementation is like the following:

`communication module` receives data and puts data into an object (an instance of a data class) when a packet is received. Then it will `fire an event` which will `contain that data object`.

`data process module` receives event and puts the received data object into an `arraylist`.

after all data for one analysis are received, `data process module` will start data process to analyze the data. At the end the data will be stored to database and those data objects will be cleanup for next analysis.

time between `each analysis` is more than 10 minutes.

I have removed the clone or copy operation during the internal data transfer process. So I think we are actually passing reference around. right? I have also created a pool for those events and data objects. so those events and data objects will be reused again and again.

Another suggestion is create a `shared reusable memory space` (internal share, between modules) for those analysis data and pass its reference around with the event. I like this idea better but more code change from me. What I did now are almost the same in terms of memory usage. am I right?

What's your opinion? any other better ideas? for the `shared reusable memory space` solution, what's the correct way to implement it?

thanks,

Comment: Did you profile the application? Where were the bottlenecks?

Comment: Which version of .NET? How many threads are you using here?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it thread safe by doing something like this.

```
public sealed class SafeBytes
{
    private readonly List<byte> _data;
    private readonly object _lock;


    public SafeBytes()
    {
        _data = new List<byte>();
        _lock = new object();
    }


    public void Add(byte[] data)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            _data.AddRange(data);
        }
    }

    public byte[] ToArray()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            return _data.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```